# Side menu is not visible in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

I have this side menu that is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE it's not visible, I've tracked down the issue to this part of my CSS:

```
    #cssmenu ul ul {
        top: 1px;
        right: 99%;
    }
```

this is responsible to move the submenu to the right/left, but whatever I do, I can't solve the issue.

[You can see the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqTPD.jpg)

My menu structure is something like this:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
/* Please Keep this font import at the very top of any CSS file */
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  background: #333333;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover a {
  background: #1b9bff;
}
#cssmenu li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  border: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0082e7;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4eb1ff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > a {
  border-left: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  border-right: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  content: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.first {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.last {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've run your snippet in IE 11 and it is working for me.

Comment: @BrankVictoria I forgot to mention, the snippet works fine, it's a sample that I've embedded into my website, but for me, it's not working. the menu is just there but it's not visible.

Comment: Probablly your css styles are overrided by another style file that you have in your website. Are you sure that the id "cssMenu" is unique and also that is not used in another css file?

Comment: @BrankVictoria I've tried removing CSS rules line by line to see what will happen, apparently it's because a border-radius that I've given to the side-menu parent, but I don't get it, border-radius is supported in IE 11 !!